# Switching sorting function with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making sorting function by Vue js

Ideal behaviour is like this,

- order `Name` by ascending order when `asc by name` button clicked  -> done :)
- order `Name` by descending order when `desc by name` button clicked  -> done :)
- switch asc/desc function on/off by clicking itself.  -> done :)
- switch asc/desc function on/off by clicking the other button  -> NOT WORKING!!

  - ex1) click `desc by name` button first, then, click `asc by name` button -> done
  - **ex2) click `asc by name` button first, then, click `desc by name` button -> NOT WORKING!!**

I added switchng function on `computed` named `sort`.

I don't even know why ex1) works but ex2) doesn't

Please help if you know.

Thanks

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    asc: false,
    desc: false,
    list: [],
  },
  created: function () {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(function (response) {
      this.list = response.data
    }.bind(this)).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e)
    })
  },
  methods: {
  },

  computed: {
    sort: function() {
      if (this.asc) {            //ordered by asc
        this.desc = false        // NOT WORKING!!!
        console.log(`this.desc ${this.desc}`);
        return _.orderBy(this.list, 'name', 'asc')

      } else if (this.desc) {   //ordered by desc
        this.asc = false
        console.log(`this.asc ${this.asc}`);
        return _.orderBy(this.list, 'name', 'desc')
      }
    },
    sorted: function() {
      if (this.asc) {
        return this.sort

      } else if (this.desc) {
        return this.sort

      } else {
        return this.list
      }
    },


  }
})
```

```css
span {font-weight: bold;}
.is-active {background: turquoise;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.17.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in sorted" :key="item.id">
      <span>ID:</span> {{item.id}} ,  <span>Name:</span> {{item.name}} ,  <span>Company:</span> {{item.company.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button :class="{'is-active': asc}"  @click="asc=!asc">asc by name</button>
  <button :class="{'is-active': desc}" @click="desc=!desc">desc by name</button>
</div>
```

Comment: asc/desc, just use one is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, computed shouldn't mutate data. If you want to do so, I'd suggest you make watchers instead.

You can notice that your application refreshes twice when togging those buttons by adding a console.log into the `updated()` lifecycle function of your component.

Change the computed part to:

```
sorted() {
  if (this.asc) {
    return _.orderBy(this.list, 'name', 'asc')
  } else if (this.desc) {
    return _.orderBy(this.list, 'name', 'desc')
  }

  return this.list
},
```

And add watchers instead:

```
watch: {
  asc(newVal) {
    if (this.desc && newVal)
      this.desc = false
  },

  desc(newVal) {
    if (this.asc && newVal)
      this.asc = false
  },
},
```

---

On the optimization side:

For most of the time you wrote `function()` you don't need it.

For the `created()` part, you can have a look at [fat arrows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to help reduce the complexity of your code.

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => this.list = response.data)
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

The component methods can be written directly as `functionName() {}` rather than `functionName: function() {}` as a shorthand for clarity.

Also, you don't need the 2 separate computed ; one is enough for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got your point(needed time to figure out). I was not familiar with `watcher` but I'm gonna use to it. Also, thanks for the coding advise. I appreciate that.